# Using morph transition in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I already have powerpoint 2016 and I don't have subscribed account so I don't have access to morph transition.

If I install powerpoint 2019 then can I access to this feature? if yes, then what about opening the powerpoint file by other person (with other system)? can it be displayed on their computer? (assume they have powerpoint 2016 or 2012 without subscribed account.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The morph transition function only exists in some versions. If you have PowerPoint2019 installed, then you can use this feature.

Other users (using PowerPoint2016 or 2012) also need to have this function to open the file you created normally.

If you use PowerPoint2019 to create a morph transition, but other users' PowerPoint versions do not support this feature, ***the files they open will not have such effects.***

For specific version information, you can refer to the following table：

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I wonder how you noticed " the files they open will not have such effects" ? did you have same experience like mine?

Comment: This is a common phenomenon in office

Comment: @soheil For quite a few versions back, PowerPoint in any version has been able to ignore or "gracefully degrade" features it doesn't understand while still preserving them in the file. This avoids a lot of the backward compatibility failures that occur with other products.